# Im getting this errno 2 when trying to copy files with python

Tags: python-3.x, file, shutil

I am trying to move a lot of files from a directory and all of it's underlying folders, but when i run my code. The script can't find the first .pdf file. Which I find strange, because the file is indeed there

```
import shutil
import os
#Change the working directory to where files are located
os.chdir("C:\\Users\\vhole\\iCloudDrive\\BA_Historie\\")

#Get current working directory
directory = os.getcwd()
print(f"Current working directory is {directory}")
#Walking through a folder tree
for folders,subfoldes,filenames in os.walk('C:\\Users\\vhole\\iCloudDrive\\BA_Historie\\'):
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.endswith('.jpg') or filename.endswith('.pdf'):
            shutil.copy(filename,'C:\\Users\\vhole\\iCloudDrive\\BA_Historie\\Samlede_tekster\\', follow_symlinks = True)
```

**This is the traceback and error i am getting:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "project13.py", line 18, in <module>
    shutil.copy(filename,'C:\\Users\\vhole\\iCloudDrive\\BA_Historie\\Samlede_tekster\\', follow_symlinks = True)
  File "C:\Users\vhole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\shutil.py", line 248, in copy
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "C:\Users\vhole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\shutil.py", line 120, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Det_moderne_Norden_program.pdf'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python tries to copy the file from the working directory (i.e., the one you chdired into).  Hence if your pdf file is not directly in it but rather in one of its sub-directories, the copy will fail.  A solution is therefore to prepend the sub-directory path to `filename`.  So instead of:

```py
            shutil.copy(filename,'C:\\Users\\vhole\\iCloudDrive\\BA_Historie\\Samlede_tekster\\', follow_symlinks = True)
```

try:

```py
            shutil.copy(os.path.join(folders, filename),'C:\\Users\\vhole\\iCloudDrive\\BA_Historie\\Samlede_tekster\\', follow_symlinks = True)
```